# How to recover Jenkins password

Tags: linux, password-recovery

I had installed Jenkins in my Ubuntu 12.04. And i forgot my Jenkins password

kumar@Ubuntu:~$ sudo su -l jenkins

jenkins@Ubuntu:~$ rvm reload

RVM reloaded!

jenkins@rome:~$ rvm install 2.0.0

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.

Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.

[sudo] password for jenkins:

Sorry, try again.

[sudo] password for jenkins:

Sorry, try again.

[sudo] password for jenkins:

Sorry, try again.

sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

Please let me know how to recover the password. Thanks

Comment: Why did you rollback my tag edits? This question has /nothing/ to do with jenkins and is all about linux passwords.

Comment: @SimonGroenewolt it's not only linux password, it has main relation to jenkins

Answer (score 2):

Login as root, do a

> passwd jenkins

if you are not root, ask the administrator of your machine to do this.

BTW: this is not really a jenkins question, I've removed the jenkins tag and added linux.

Update: you might not have a root user with a password on your system, but your kumar user probably has sufficient rights using sudo. (sudo without specifying a user basically means 'do as root')

> sudo passwd jenkins

now you have to pay attention, since the first password you have to type is the password of your kumar user, and only after that the system will ask you for the new jenkins user password.

Comment: Thanks but Please let me know, how to Login as root

Comment: you could do `sudo bash` and enter your password as it looks like you have sudo setup for your account

Answer (score 0):

Your default username is "admin" and password you can copy from this path/command : cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/InitialAdminPassword