# How can I find initial password for jenkins?

Tags: macos, jenkins

I already searched the related questions like here;

[How do I get initial admin password for jenkins on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146063/how-do-i-get-initial-admin-password-for-jenkins-on-mac)

and here;

[How to recover Jenkins password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467139/how-to-recover-jenkins-password)

However, I cannot find a solution for my problem.

I am following the instructions to install jenkins on this link;

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/

and I have run the following commands to install and tried to make it run on my local machine (mac os);

```
docker run \
  -u root \
  --rm \
  -d \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -p 50000:50000 \
  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

It installs it properly but when I get to the login screen it asks for the initial admin password. Because the installation runs in (-d mode) backend, I cannot see the initial password after the installation completes. When I remove -d for the installation, then the installation does not work.

I also checked the shared folder (User/Shared/Jenkins/Home) directory and there was no `secrets` folder in it. So I created one manually and followed the instructions (in the answers) on this link again;

[How do I get initial admin password for jenkins on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146063/how-do-i-get-initial-admin-password-for-jenkins-on-mac)

Afterwards, I removed the related docker process and restarted all the installation process from the beginning but I got the same result.

In this case, how can I find this initial admin password or how can I generate it again?

BTW: I am also checking the logs (where in `/var/log/jenkins`) but it seems that it stopped writing there after my first install attempt and I also couldn't find the initial password there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you install docker-compose and docker toolbox on your Mac? 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/
Try to execute this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  blue-ocean:
    image: jenkinsci/blueocean:latest
    container_name: blue-ocean
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: America/Mexico_City
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - ./sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Only you need to create a folder with a docker-compose.yml file inside and execute the `docker-compose up -d` command in terminal, then the folders jenkins-data and sock will be created and inside of jenkins-data appear the directory ./jenkins-data/secrets/initialAdminPassword, open this file and copy the content and paste on the input of web view that requires it.

Comment: Hi, I don't have 'secrets' folder in 'jenkins-data' folder. So, I cannot find the initialAdminPassword file. Why does that happen?

Comment: After awhile, the 'secrets' folder was created. Now, I found it and could pass the password page :) Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe this answer is not good. Why? Although it works, it is not answering with an actionable solution for the problem so it shouldn't be taken as acceptable answer.
Also @user2147431 should be made aware that the folder ".../secrets/..." is not on the host OS (macOS, Linux, whatever... is the same on every Docker deployment) but on the guest/container's once it's bootstrapped.

Answer (score 59):

`docker exec <container_name> cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

Comment: This worked for me but looking at the logs did not.

Comment: This should be actually the accepted response. I mean: there's no use on reconstructing the whole container or the logging part referencing out the password could well have been lost/passed.

Comment: What I can do if I can't find that file?

Comment: Works like Charm

Answer (score 30):

I tried looking into the container's filesystem, but there's no secrets folder in it. But I found the solution in the jenkins documentation [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#setup-wizard)

**Docker outputs the initial secret to the console**

To view the console use the command

```
docker logs <container id of jenkins>
```

output is somemthing like this:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Mac and Docker installation for Jenkins follow bellow steps to get initial administer password to start authentication in Jenkins Console. Type below command in Terminal.

(Note: This is working, if you have follow default steps in Jenkins documentation to install Jenkins in Docker environment)

Find the running containers

```
: docker ps
```

Copy the running containerID

```
: docker exec -it <containerID> bash

: cd /var/jenkins_home/secrets

: cat initialAdminPassword
```

Use secret password showing in terminal and used as initial password for Jenkins Console.

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed Jenkins via docker, then the following command can give you the initial admin password. Assuming your container name/docker image name is *jenkins*

```
docker exec `docker ps | grep jenkins | awk '{ print $1}' ` cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Comment: Worked great for me. I had to replace instances of `docker` with `sudo docker`.

Comment: Use `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` if want to avoid typing sudo all the time

Answer (score 3):

docker exec $(docker ps -q) cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

Answer (score 3):

For me username was: admin
and you can find password by:

```
docker exec jenkins cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

my container name is jenkins